# Can't understand simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am very new to bash scripts so I can't really understand what this line below does:

```
[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

This double square brackets is an if statement I guess. And I understand that we transform **"Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n"** into **config** file, but what is everything else over there. Some documentation or tutorials for newbie is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[ ... ]]` is a function that evaluates the statement inside it and returns either true or false.

`-f` means "file exists": http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

`&&` means "and" which means execute the next statement if the previous statement returned true

`echo -e` means print the string in the second argument to stdout and interpret escape sequences e.g. "\n".

`> ~/.ssh/config` means write the stdout of the preceding statement to "~/.ssh/config"

The long hand and possibly easier to understand version of this would be:

```
if [[ -f /.dockerenv ]]; then
   echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
fi
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `>` overwrites the entire file.

Answer (score 4):

In short: It tells ssh to automatically add host keys to known hosts regardless of whether it's knows or changed.

It's a shorthand for:

```
if [[ -f /.dockerenv ]]; then
    echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
fi
```

`[[...]]` is bash built-in test. And `&&` means, the following command is run if the previous has succeeded (returned `0`). I.e. if `/.dockerenv` file exists and is a file, it echos (interpreting backslash escapes `-e`):

```
Host *
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Followed by two training newlines into `~/.ssh/config` (replacing any content that might have been there). It however assumes the directory `~/.ssh` to already exist and would fail if it did not.

Comment: you're welcome... BTW. this kind of shows why `if` is a meaningful choice over conditionally chaining commands... It's obvious and makes sense at first sight regardless of the reader's background.